# What were Odell and Maya up to?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, black-lightning-2018

In the episode "Painkiller," it is revealed that Odell and his daughter, Maya, have been kidnapping people and using their brainpower to mine cryotocurrency. However, Khalil's crew seems to think that there was much more behind the project than that, and knowing Odell, he must have been right.

Curiously, the season and the series end without an obvious statement about Odell's aims, even as recurring villains like Looker tie into the main plotline.

Is there any hint in the rest of the series, in Odell's character, or in the episode "Painkiller" that suggests what Odell's new aims are?